# I'm getting java.util.InputMismatchException when the input type matches the expected type

Tags: java

This code is in the main method:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = input.nextInt();
```

I need to input a 16-digit integer. I get `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

I cannot figure why this is, as an int is expected and I enter an int. Is 16 digits too long?

Comment: The max value for an int is `2147483647`. Or in other words, yes 16 digits is too big to store in an int

Answer (score 2):

Integer goes from -2147483648 to 2147483647 so... yeah... 16 digits is too 'Long'.
Try long which max value is 9223372036854775807.